# Why does the meta "viewport" tag make my page looked zoomed in on Android device?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, meta-tags, viewport

I'm trying to make my site more "responsive" on mobile devices.

http://healthybodyguru.com

I've tried a lot of variations of the "viewport" meta tag, which is currently:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

But for some reason on my HTC Vivid, the page loads quite zoomed in:

[image: HTC Vivid Screeny]

Any ideas how I can adjust the viewport so the page is 100% visible on my Android?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

I'm still trying to understand the `viewport` to be honest. But I think, I maybe got it now. The viewport `width` should be set to the default viewable width of the content. For example: If you just have an `<img/>` with `width: 320px`, than the image will be fullscreen if you use the code above.

Comment: Nope, looks exactly the same.  I'm even using the Chrome dev tools to debug from my PC, so I can make sure it's not a caching issue.

Comment: @Kane, I made an update, maybe this helps. But as far as I can see, your layout is not very response right now, maybe you change it later. But currently your minimal width is around 1000px. This should be your viewport width.

Comment: Nope, still isn't the solution, if I set it to 1000px I can't use @media CSS queries to hide the sidebar, set a drop-down menu, etc.  I think you're right, the HTML/CSS layout needs some work before it can be truly responsive.

Comment: Well, of course not. But currently it seems the minimum width of your page is around 1000. your media queries seem not to change that. If you made a special layout for let's say a screen width of `320px <= x <= 480px`, then you can set the viewport width to `320px`, because that's the min width your styles can handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
initial-scale=1
```

Is causing it to load zoomed in. You can either remove it, or replace it with maximum-scale or minimum-scale (for whatever you're trying to achieve).

Comment: I changed it to only say "width=device-width" but it still loads exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me great ... I hope it will work for you too ...

```
// fit the width of screen
myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); 
// remove a weird white line on the right size
myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```